# Populate a 2D Array with ints

Tags: java

Title is slightly confusing... Sorry.

I have to answer a question, and I started it, but I'm not 100% sure of what is being asked. Perhaps one of you understand it.

Here is the question:

Write the code for populating a 2-D array of ints that models a multiplication table. The array should have 12 rows and 12 columns. Each entry in the ‘table’ should be the product of the row*col -- e.g. The element at arr[2][3] = 6 and the element at arr[0][11] = 0.

Here is what I have so far, but I don't know how to continue:

```
int arr[][] = new int[12][12];
    int mult;

    for(int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col < arr[1].length; col++){

        }  
    }
```

Comment: `arr[row][col] = row*col;` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically a 2d array can store value (for a tutorial click [here](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/multi-dimensional_arrays.html)). What you want to do is save the value in the block it self.

```
int arr[][] = new int[12][12];
for(int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++){
    for(int col = 0; col < arr[1].length; col++){
           arr[row][col]=row*col;
    }  
}
```

Then use a double for loop to see the output like:

```
for(int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++){
    for(int col = 0; col < arr[1].length; col++){
           System.out.print(row +" * " col + " = "+arr[row][col]+"  ");
    }  
System.out.println();
}
```